# Bootstrap 3 Navbar with Table (with scrollbars) overlapping

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-tables

I'm hoping for some help, I have a static navbar along with some buttons on the right, and I have a VERY large table that the users are going to interact with.

The users are most familar with an Excel like view where there is a ribbon (my navbar) on top and the table is scrolled horizontal and vertically as necessary.

I've got the table to fill the page and have the bootstrap static navbar to show however **the navbar is overlapping the table headers.**

Is there an easy way to fix this overlap?

Here is bootstrap playground link detailing what I currently have.
https://www.bootply.com/iGX9K2KF9a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, give the `.table-wrapper` a `margin-top:50px` and that will move it down. Since the navbar is fixed, it's taken out of the flow of the page so the relatively positioned `.table-wrapper` is still being placed based off the top of the page.

Comment: Knew it was an easy fix. Thank you!